# Why can't we access semaphore

Tags: linux, semaphore

I was reading about semaphores, and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/process-synchronization-set-1/) I found that you can not access (increment/decrement) a **semaphore** directly.

> A Semaphore is an integer variable, which can be accessed only through two operations wait() and signal().

I have two questions regarding the topic:

1. What is the type of semaphores. Is it a structure or some other datatype.

If it is a structure then my second question is:

2. Why can't we access the semaphores with `semaphore.some_value++`.

And if it is a variable which I found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) :

> A trivial semaphore is a plain variable
>   Then why can't we access it like `semaphore1++`?

I tried to increment it and got this error:

> error: wrong type argument to increment

Why is it forbidden from the user, why do we have to use the functions to access it? (Although I agree, that it is not a bad practice to use functions, but Why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of a semaphore is not merely in the incrementing and decrementing of an integer, but also in the communication between the semaphore's users. The communication aspect is what is encapsulated by the `wait` and `signal` functions. In particular, on most operating systems, they will use lower-level kernel features so that the `wait` doesn't need to waste CPU repeatedly checking the semaphore's value.

The fact that you received that compiler error shows that, on your system, a semaphore is a structure. However, you would not be able to use the semaphore by accessing the structure members directly, because that would not affect the underlying kernel object.

Comment: So, basically there is some more code under the `wait()` definition in `semaphore.h` file, which helps in synchronization and not only the value of semaphore, and the user shouldn't bother himself for those operations?

Comment: And that if I forcibly try to change it's value, It might cause some errors.

Comment: Yes, and the code is not only under the `wait()` definition, but also in the kernel scheduler which decides which thread is allowed to run.